# Why does the ping command in my batch file execute in a loop?

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, ping

I created a .BAT file in Windows 7 that has the following line:

```
PING XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -t
```

(XXX replaces the actual IP number). However, when I double click on this batch file, I can see the ping command repeatedly being executed in a loop. I even tried to rename the `ping.BAT` to `ping.CMD` but the result is the same.

I want to avoid writing ping command through the command prompt, which is why I created the batch file. I don't know why the ping command is being continuously called when the same statement is put in a batch file.

Comment: Actually repeating or you see it pinging forever? Because that's what `-t` does.

Comment: ping 127.0.0.1 -t  <-- from cmd prompt, it does repeatedly. and that's not in a batch file (tested in win xp)

Comment: you're supposed to put the - switch before the host anyway. ping -t 127.0.0.1  but does the same thing. and is meant to. why use -t if you don't want infinite, see ping -? so your question is profoundly strange

Comment: "I don't know whey the PING command is being continuously called when the same statement is put in a batch file." <-- do you stand by this?

Comment: I still haven't found a solution. I see the PING command being repeatedly called without any result.

Comment: Could you copy the output of your batch file ? And try « @ping -t 127.0.0.1 »

Comment: Did you try changing the name in the batch file to ping.exe? E.g. 'ping.exe -t XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` which prevents the batch file from accidentally calling itself again.

Comment: reading the fine manual would give you that answer.

Comment: you may want to check your documentation on this. ping /help on windows or man ping on nix like systems.

Answer (score 16):

It is a bit unclear what is exactly the problem you face since you don't provide any output or screenshot of what you don't like, but I'll explain the two most likely problems I see:

Given your script is called `ping.bat` and looks like this:

```
 ping example.com
```

then the interpreter (`cmd.exe`) searches/probes the paths in the environment variable `%PATH%` for something that looks like `ping` ... and it does that by appending each suffix from `%PATHEXT%` which contains something like `.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC`. so, calling just `ping` from the `ping.bat`leads to a search for `ping.com` `ping.exe` `ping.bat` and so on. The interpreter will find a `ping.bat` in the current working directory (your `ping.bat`) and calls it.

So, you will have a nice [recursion](https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion) here: ping.cmd executes the first line, searches for "ping", finds "ping.cmd", executes the first line, searches for "ping", finds "ping.cmd", executes the first line, searches for "ping", finds "ping.cmd" ...

The second problem you might have is this:

The interpreter of the batch file will usually repeat the commands you have written to the .bat/.cmd file. Thus something like this `ping www.superuser.com` will look like this:

```
 C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop>ping www.superuser.com

 Ping wird ausgeführt für superuser.com [64.34.119.12] mit 32 Bytes Daten:
 Antwort von 64.34.119.12: Bytes=32 Zeit=110ms TTL=46
 Antwort von 64.34.119.12: Bytes=32 Zeit=107ms TTL=46
```

If you want to get rid of `C:\Users\XYZ\Desktop>ping www.superuser.com` in the output of the script then you have to either prepend each line with an `@` (for example, '@ping www.superuser.com') in the script or place a `@echo off` before the bunch of command lines you want to execute "quietly".

**TL;DR;**
**Don't call your bat files the same as existing programs.**

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem,

ping.bat contained several lines of ping command

```
ping host1
ping host2
ping host3
...
```

output in cmd shell looked as below and continued in a loop on and on until the break with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

```
c:\ping host1    
c:\ping host1    
c:\ping host1    
c:\ping host1    
c:\ping host1
...

c:\ping host1
^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)?
```

To solve it, just rename the `ping.bat`, so it doesn't call itself in the batch file or use ping.exe as the command in the batch file

```
ping.exe host1
ping.exe host2
ping.exe host3
...
```

Answer (score 3):

The -t parameter makes the ping continuous.

Maybe remove the -t parameter and then tell your batch script to wait for you to press enter before killing the cmd screen.

Haven't used windows in a while but this should work:

```
ping xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
pause
exit
```

Comment: removing -t didn't work. Could you please post the script?

Comment: @pradeetp added some code above

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issues. Here is the resolution:

Rename your ping.bat file to pingtest.bat

And ensure it contains:

ping xxx.xxx.xxx.001
ping xxx.xxx.xxx.002
ping xxx.xxx.xxx.003
pause

This will allow you to ping one or multiple addresses and will show the results on screen. This batch file can be run from anywhere on your PC by double clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

The local script execution seems to prevent ping.exe from running in a script.  Try right-clicking, and "run as administrator".  I'm looking up how to update the execution policy.

Just when I thought I knew something about Windows, they changed it.

---

Update:  Recursion is the answer...

You can't call it ping.bat and call ping.exe

You also can't call it route.bat and call route.exe.

e.g, when I run ping.bat, then run it again as pingx.bat: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Right click  - Run As Administrator worked for me.

Comment: I could swear that this isn't correct and tested it - and he is right O_O

Answer (score -1):

It is because you name the batch file same as the ping command is named. Rename your batch file to something else. Etc.: myping.bat

Answer (score -2):

In other words, **do not name your batch file (ping)**. Use any other file name you want. And the following code will work perfectly.

```
@echo off
PING XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
pause
```

Comment: That answer is the same as stefan and akira already gave. Only shorter